# jQuery set selected in chained select dropdown using modal AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem to display data using chained selected dropdown using AJAX in Modal.

I have successfully used the feature and it runs smoothly, but the problem is when I want to 'edit' and want to display the data on chained selected dropdown using AJAX in Modal.

I tried using a `trigger ('change');` but only affects the first select. The second select and so on are unsuccessful, and cannot call the onchange function because the second or so select does not change to get the next chain. Please help.

```
$('#country').val(res.data.country).trigger('change');
$('#state').val(res.data.state).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? You have two dropdowns with the ids `#country` and `#state`. And when `#country` changes, you want to set the value of `#state`to `res.data.state`. Is that correct?

Comment: yes correct, there is more dropdown after state. i just put two for example

Comment: after state changes, i using on change to call ajax again to show city and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to **trigger** change events, you need to **listen** for them. Change events are automatically triggered when the user changes the value of your select.
Try something like:

```js
// Listen for changes on country
$('#country').change(function() {
  // Your logic that should run when country's value changes
  $('#state').val(res.data.state);
});
```

Comment: when i add console.log('success'); it still show the message :(
I don't know why selecting the state isn't working

Comment: What does `console.log(res.data.state)` inside the country change callback output?

Comment: Can you please provide a full code example that shows the error.

Comment: sure here is the code when user click edit button and then show the modal https://pastebin.pl/view/6b6b3970

Comment: Can you show the HTML also? Maybe you did not define the value of `res.data.state` inside the `<options></options>` of the state select?